# How can we safely reuse a dataframe reading a Hive table using HiveWarehouseConnector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

When using the same dataframe reading a Hive table using `HiveWarehouseConnector` multiple times an exception occurs during computation.

Example :

```scala
val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build()

hive.setDatabase("db")
val df_data = hive.table("table")

val df_one_col = df_data.select("col1")
val df_two_col = df_data.select("col1", "col2")

val df_res = df_two_col.join(df_one_col, "col1")

df_res.show()
```

We get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` during task execution :

```
20/01/15 19:46:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 18, host, executor 1): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch.column(ColumnarBatch.java:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.datasourcev2scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The generated code where the exception occurs is the following at line 39 :

```
/* 031 */   ...
/* 032 */   private void datasourcev2scan_nextBatch_0() throws java.io.IOException {
/* 033 */     long getBatchStart = System.nanoTime();
/* 034 */     if (datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_0[0].hasNext()) {
/* 035 */       datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_1[0] = (org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch)datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_0[0].next();
/* 036 */       ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[0] /* numOutputRows */).add(datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_1[0].numRows());
/* 037 */       datasourcev2scan_batchIdx_0 = 0;
/* 038 */       datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_2[0] = (org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnVector) datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_1[0].column(0);
/* 039 */       datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_2[1] = (org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnVector) datasourcev2scan_mutableStateArray_1[0].column(1);
/* 040 */
/* 041 */     }
/* 042 */     datasourcev2scan_scanTime_0 += System.nanoTime() - getBatchStart;
/* 043 */   }
/* 044 */   ...
```

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when the second column is accessed.

The physical plan is the following :

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) Project [col1#333, col2#334]
+- *(5) SortMergeJoin [col1#333], [col1#390], Inner
   :- *(2) Sort [col1#333 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col1#333, 200)
   :     +- *(1) DataSourceV2Scan [col1#333, col2#334], com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader@4527e4
   +- *(4) Sort [col1#390 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col1#390, 200)
         +- *(3) DataSourceV2Scan [col1#390], com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader@4527e4
```

We can see that we use the same HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader instance.

The Spark logs show that the two Hive queries fired only ask for 'col1' column.

```
20/01/15 19:46:32 INFO LlapBaseInputFormat: Handle ID c259528d-60ac-42d5-a201-9646335151dd: query=select `col1` from (SELECT * FROM table) as q_d89e3f8df0cd4ce3bdf4c7d938c006ad WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
...
20/01/15 19:46:35 INFO LlapBaseInputFormat: Handle ID c259528d-60ac-42d5-a201-9646335151dd: query=select `col1` from (SELECT * FROM table) as q_76d9b5c5a5af482a8a3e671b6c8421a8 WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

During Spark logical plan optimization, column pruning happened two times on the same `HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader` instance leaving the required columns to be only 'col1'. 
It seems surprising that the `DataSourceV2Relation`, depending on the mutable reader, is mutable.

**I am looking for a solution to safely reuse a dataframe reading a Hive table using `HiveWarehouseConnector`.**

I use HDP 3.1.0 with the following components :
 - Apache Spark 2.3.2
 - spark-llap HiveWarehouseConnector 1.0.0
 - Hive 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Spark 2.4**
`DataSourceV2` has been improved, especially by [SPARK-23203 DataSourceV2 should use immutable trees](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23203)

**Spark 2.3**
Disable column pruning in the `HiveWarehouseConnector` datasource reader.

Hortonworks has already fixed this issue, as stated by the [HDP 3.1.5 Release Notes](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/release-notes/content/fixed_issues.html).
We can find the correction in its [HiveWarehouseConnector github repository](https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-warehouse-connector-release/tree/HDP-3.1.5.1-2-tag) :

```java
    if (useSpark23xReader) {
      LOG.info("Using reader HiveWarehouseDataSourceReaderForSpark23x with column pruning disabled");
      return new HiveWarehouseDataSourceReaderForSpark23x(params);
    } else if (disablePruningPushdown) {
      LOG.info("Using reader HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader with column pruning and filter pushdown disabled");
      return new HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader(params);
    } else {
      LOG.info("Using reader PrunedFilteredHiveWarehouseDataSourceReader");
      return new PrunedFilteredHiveWarehouseDataSourceReader(params);
    }
```

Also, the [HDP 3.1.5 Hive integration doc](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/integrating-hive/hive_integrating_hive_and_bi.pdf) specify :

> To prevent data correctness issues in this release, pruning and projection pushdown is disabled by default.
>   ...
>   To prevent these issues and ensure correct results, do not enable pruning and pushdowns.